# C# FileHelpers - Write new record to csv without using an input file

Tags: c#, .net, csv, filehelpers

Every place I have looked all I can find is how to read a csv file into FileHelpers and then write out that same data.  I am trying to build a Record class, based on input from other areas of the app I will set the value of each record and then output the line to a csv.

So I want to have some like this:

```
[DelimitedRecord(",")]
public class Records
{
    [FieldNullValue(typeof(String), "")]
    public static string data1;

    [FieldNullValue(typeof(String), "")]
    public static string data2;

    [FieldNullValue(typeof(String), "")]
    public static string data3;
}
```

And then in another class I will set these records:

```
public class Class
{
    public static void Method()
    {
        Records.data1 = "Something";
        Records.data2 = "Something";
        Records.data3 = "Something";
    }
}
```

Its from this point I am confused about how to write these records to a csv file or a List that I can then later write to a csv file.  When I try to create the engine

```
DelimitedFileEngine e = new DelimitedFileEngine(typeof(Records));
```

I get an error that says "The record class Records don't contains any field".  Anyone have any idea what I am missing?  I cant find anywhere in the documentation where it explains how to do this.

Comment: try without using static fields

Comment: Have you tried making your properties not static?

Comment: I get the "An object reference is required for the non-static field" error when I do that.

Comment: @Ron: You need to create an instance of your Records class and then set the properties on that instance.

Comment: Still not getting it..I removed the static from the property and removed the "Records.data1 = "Something" so that now the DelimitedFileEngine works so it reads in the record class.  I created an instance of the class like: Records[] rec = new Records[];  (That might be wrong) but I cant figure out how to set the value of the variables in the record now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to start try something like this

```
[DelimitedRecord(",")]
public class Records
{
    [FieldNullValue(typeof(String), "")]
    public string data1;

    [FieldNullValue(typeof(String), "")]
    public string data2;

    [FieldNullValue(typeof(String), "")]
    public string data3;
}


public class Class
{
    public static void Method()
    {
        Records r= new Records();
        r.data1 = "Something";
        r.data2 = "Something";
        r.data3 = "Something";
    }
}
```

This allows you to create an object and to add Data... Maybe a quick review of OOP might help.

Comment: I see, thanks.  I was trying to create the class as an array.

Comment: Do you need an array of this class (something like Records[] r) or a class containing an array? In the first case something like Records[] r; r = new Records[10]; should do